# Can I still get a key to the hotel room after Boone joins me?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Already found out who the culprit was and donned the special hat during a stroll out in front of the dinosaur, now after a dialogue with Boone he has joined me.

Question remains, how can I get a key to the hotel room at this point if possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go talk to Cliff Briscoe inside the dinosaur. Once your rep with Novac is 'Accepted', you'll get a permanent key from him.

Comment: Any idea how to gain such acceptance?

Comment: Do quests in Novac. Come Fly With Me should be enough on it's own.